# Devise - Logging out of one Namespace, logs out of all Namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

My app has "users" for the main app and "admin_users" and the /admin Namespace.

When I'm logged into the /admin Namespace as an admin_user, and click "log out" - Devise logs me out of both Namespaces. How can I ensure that Devise only logs me out of that Namespace?

**Routes.rb**

```
  devise_for :users, skip: :all
  as :user do
    get 'signin',        to: 'devise/sessions#new',       as: :new_user_session
    post 'signin',       to: 'devise/sessions#create',    as: :user_session
    delete 'signout',    to: 'devise/sessions#destroy',   as: :destroy_user_session
  end

  devise_for :admins, skip: :all
  as :admin do
    get 'admin/signin',        to: 'admin/devise/sessions#new', as: :new_admin_session
    post 'admin/signin',       to: 'admin/devise/sessions#create', as: :admin_session
    delete 'admin/signout',    to: 'admin/devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_admin_session
  end

  authenticate :admin do
    namespace :admin do
       ...
    end
  end
```

Comment: Did you set `config.sign_out_all_scopes = false` in `config/initializers/devise.rb`? It defaults to true.

Comment: @max how did I miss that? Thank you, that works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `config.sign_out_all_scopes = false` in `config/initializers/devise.rb`.

```
  # Set this configuration to false if you want /users/sign_out to sign out
  # only the current scope. By default, Devise signs out all scopes.
  config.sign_out_all_scopes = false
```